# Why is Mockito giving me a new map instance?

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, hashmap, mockito

I have a simple POJO that contains a `Map<String,Widget>` property:

```
private Map<String, Widget> widgetCache = new HashMap<String, Widget>();

@Override
public Logger newWidget(String name, Widget widget) {
    // First, print the contents of widgetCache in pretty print format.
    Map<String, Widget> map = widgetCache;
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
    System.out.println("Printing..." + keys.size());
    for (String key: keys)
        System.out.println(key + ": " + map.get(key).getName());

    if(!widgetCache.containsKey(name)) {
        System.err.println("I don't contain " + name);
        widgetCache.put(name, widget);
    }

    return widgetCache.get(name);
}
```

Simple enough: it just doesn't allow duplicate `Widget`s from being inserted into the map. When I go to test this in a JUnit test method using Mockito (1.9.5):

```
CachingWidgetFactory fixture = new CachingWidgetFactory();

// By the way, I get errors if I try to make this next line:
//        HashMap<String,Widget> mockMap = Mockito.mock(HashMap<String,Widget>.class);
// How do I enforce generics here when defining a mock?
HashMap mockMap = Mockito.mock(HashMap.class);

fixture.setLoggerCache(mockMap);

fixture.newWidget("Widget-A", new Widget("Widget-A"));
fixture.newWidget("Widget-A", new Widget("Widget-A"));

Mockito.verify(mockMap, Mockito.times(1))
        .put(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.<Logger>any());
```

I get the test **failing** with the following JUnit output:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
hashMap.put(<any>, <any>);
Wanted 1 time:
```

And in the (STDOUT) console output, I see this:

```
Printing...0
I don't contain Widget-A
Printing...0
I don't contain Widget-A
```

So it looks like the mock that Mockito is returning is allowing the 2nd (duplicate) insert. However, when I remove the Mockito `mockMap` entirely, and make the test method look like:

```
CachingWidgetFactory fixture = new CachingWidgetFactory();

fixture.newWidget("Widget-A", new Widget("Widget-A"));
fixture.newWidget("Widget-A", new Widget("Widget-A"));
```

Then in the console output, I get:

```
Printing...0
I don't contain Widget-A
Printing...1
```

Now the (non-mocked) code is correctly preventing the duplicate insert. So it's almost as if Mockito is returning a new `HashMap` every time `newWidget` is being called. What's going on here, and why? (And bonus points if you can help me on the generic issue mentioned above.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend against mocking HashMap.  During testing you don't need to mock everything not being tested.  You just need to be able to trust everything.  So, in my testing I usually don't mock Collections, Lists, Sets, or Maps from the JDK.  In general, it is easier to load a real collection with Mock objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a common mistake. You have to remember that you mocked `HashMap`. So, mockito is not giving you a new map everytime, it just don't know how to behave because you mocked the HashMap.

Giving that, it will behave as you tell it to behave. If you haven't said anything, it will return default values/do nothing when you call your methods. So, at the line

```
 if (!widgetCache.containsKey(name))
```

because you didnt say how it should behave, it will return the default value of `false`. You can mock the map to return false at the second call using Mockito with something like

```
 given(hashMap.containsKey(name)).willReturn(false, true);
```

With that, HashMap will return that "contains" the key at the second call of `containsKey` with the given name. You can read its documentation [here](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/BDDMockito.BDDMyOngoingStubbing.html#willReturn%28T,%20T...%29)

Another thing you could do is to give to it a real implementation of HashMap, but I prefer the "mock" way :)

**EDIT**

I gave the link to BDDMockito, but it works the same way with `when`->`thenReturn`. It's just syntax sugar :) I find it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
// How do I enforce generics here when defining a mock?
HashMap mockMap = Mockito.mock(HashMap.class);
```

Handling generics is much easier if you use the mockito annotations, e.g.

```
@Mock
HashMap<String, Widget> mockMap;
```

and then in your setup method:

```
MockitoAnnotations.init(this);
```

But to your problem, just use

```
HashMap<String, Widget> map=new HashMap<String, Widget>();
```

so that the test uses a real HashMap that behaves like one, since that is the thing you want to test. If you're going to mock all the HashMap operations yourself, chances are you are making some kind of mistake (like forgetting to mock a method).

Comment: I imagine the class he is testing is `CachingWidgetFactory`. He actually expose a method to set the "cacheMap". You can see at `fixture.setLoggerCache(mockMap);`. But I agree that that the class seems strange.

Comment: I agree that the map isn't part of the class being tested. One would expect however, that any reasonable Map would follow the contract of Map (e.g. regarding contains() etc.)

Comment: totally agree :) but mocks only respect what you tell them to respect. That's why is preferable for him to use an instance of HashMap as you pointed. It would be even better if he created a "Cache" class that uses a Map behind. Then, he could mock the cache class :P